# Can't get data from second row when using cursor.fetchall()

Tags: python, mysql

```
 cursor.execute("""SELECT content, COUNT(*)
                   FROM Attachments
                   WHERE id = 123""")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print str(results[0][1]) # prints 3, meaning there are three rows returned
print results[1].content # IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The query returns three rows, yet I am only able to access the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COUNT(*)` causes MySQL to aggregate all the rows into one. The `content` field will be a single value from *any* of the aggregated rows.

To get all the rows, use

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT content
                   FROM Attachments
                   WHERE id = 123""")
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Then you can look at `len(results)` to obtain the count:

```
print(len(results)) # prints 3, meaning there are three rows returned
```

and get the second row using:

```
print(results[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood how `cursor.fetchall()` works. It returns a list of all rows, of which the length can be checked with

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
print len(results)
```

which should return 1 by the looks of the index error.

If you access `results[0][1]` you are accessing whatever is at index 1 in the first row, which seems to be 3.

Comment: What do you mean by "a list of all rows?" `results[0][1]` == COUNT(*) in the first row. I'm trying to figure out how to access results[1], i.e., the second row.

Comment: best look at @HappyLeapSecond 's answer. I didnt take into concideration, that COUN(*) just returns one row